# Routing problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a user managment system where users can be dragged and dropped along different groups (copy and move users). I use

```
drop_receiving_element "move_drop_zone_1", 
  :update => "users", 
  :url => move_user_path(:target_node_id => node.id),
  :method => :put,
  :accept => "move_user", 
  :hoverclass => "node-active"
```

to define a dropzone.

I have a problem with the path. Above code results in

> move_user_url failed to generate from
>   {:action=>"move",
>   :controller=>"users",
>   :target_node_id=>2}, expected:
>   {:action=>"move",
>   :controller=>"users"}, diff:
>   {:target_node_id=>2}

In my routes i defined `map.resources :users, :member => { :move => :put, :copy => :put }`

Apparently Rails is not expecting the target_node_id but how can I include this?

thanks
Stijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move_user_path is a "member" path. Therefore, you will also need to provide the :id for the user member you are referring to.

So you might have:

```
move_user_path(:id => current_user.id, :target_node_id => node.id)
```

Or, you will need to change your routes to:

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :move => :put, :copy => :put }
```

And then your path becomes:

```
move_users_path(:target_node_id => node.id)
```

Hope this helps.

Joerg

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still some problems...
When I do 
<%= link_to "move user", move_users_path(:target_node_id => 1), :method => :put %> 
the update method of the users controller gets called and not the move. 
<%= link_to "move user", move_users_path(:target_node_id => 1) %> 
the show method of the users controller gets called and not the move. 

I defined map.resources :users, :collection => { :move => :put, :copy => :put } in routes

Answer (score 1):

Joerg is right.

Also, a very good resource to learn more about routing is on [Ruby On Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)